# How many displays/monitors can a Mac Mini 2012 support?

Tags: display, mac-mini

I know the 2012 mini has 2 video outputs but I've seen in the past PCs where one DVI output could be split to two displays.

So is the limit one monitor per physical display port (HDMI & whichever proprietary socket Apple were using that month) or something else?

Answer (score 1):

From Everymac... http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i7-2.3-late-2012-specs.html

2nd Display Support:    Dual/Mirroring* 2nd Max. Resolution:    2560x1600*

*This model simultaneously supports 1920x1200 on an HDMI or a DVI display (using the included HDMI-to-DVI adapter) and 2560x1600 on a Thunderbolt or Mini DisplayPort display or even a VGA display (with an optional Mini DisplayPort-to-VGA adapter, which is compatible with the Thunderbolt port).

Comment: This link show you can also have dual thunderbolt monitors so the complete list of options isn't clear...

Comment: where? quote it.

Comment: Sorry forgot to paste http://osxdaily.com/2014/01/25/mac-setups-mac-mini-dual-thunderbolt-displays/

Comment: I'd relate that back to Everymac - they are very fastidious about maintaining an accurate database